# openSSH and LDAP for Windows

Tags: ssh, ldap, openssh

is it possible to use the LDAP / Active Directory with OpenSSH ?
That is avoiding using the commands "mkgroup -d..." and "mkpasswd -d ..." of OpenSSH. These commands are used to define an user list allowed to access to the "ssh server" machine... and I would like to avoid having a fixed list not to have to relaunch the commands several times.

I use OpenSSH as a SSH server and putty as a client.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I can not determine which OS you OpenSSH is running on?

Assuming it it Linux/UNIX, AFAIK, you would want to setup using PAM (Pluggable Authentication Module).

Google for PAM LDAP Linux

One link is:
http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Pam_ldap